# fgets() not behaving as intended , kind of "spills" into a following fgets()

Tags: c, fgets

this program lets the user enter a string and then asks what to do ( have deleted the parts that actually do stuff to make everything lighter and the problem easier to spot). The problem is that whenever a string longer than 256 characters is entered, it kinda "spills" into the following `fgets()`, which in turn prints `"insert a valid input"`.

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("your string:\n");
    char stringa[257];
    fgets(stringa, 257, stdin);
    
    for (int i = 0; stringa[i]; i++) {
        stringa[i] = tolower(stringa[i]);
    }

    char stringakek[257];
    int j= 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; stringa[i]; i++) {
        if (stringa[i] >= 'a' && stringa[i] <= 'z' && stringa[i] != '\0') {
            stringakek[j] = stringa[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    printf("this is your string all in lowercase and containing only letters: %s\n", stringakek);
    printf("what do you want to do?\n");
    printf("press 1 for case 1\n");
    printf("press 2 for case 2\n");
    printf("press 3 for case 3\n");

    int controllo = 0;
    char a[300000];

    while (controllo == 0) {
        fgets(a, 300000, stdin);
  
        switch(a[0]) {
            case '1':
            printf("case 1\n");
            controllo = 1;
            break;

            case '2':
            printf("case 2\n");
            controllo = 1;
            break;

            case '3':
            printf("case 3\n");
            controllo = 1;
            break;
    
            default:
            printf("insert a valid input\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

For example if something like

```
*R3HQ53BAQ5I4GAERÈ+ÒÈGA43IOHAUNVKANE124RÈ+fioureahjkgaeu+-reR3HQ53BAQ5I4GAERÈ+ÒÈGA43IOHAUNVKANE124RÈ+fioureahjkgaeu+-reR3HQ53BAQ5I4GAERÈ+ÒÈGA43IOHAUNVKANE124RÈ+fioureahjkgaeu+-reR3HQ53BAQ5I4GAERÈ+ÒÈGA43IOHAUNVKANE124RÈ+fioureahjkgaeu+-reR3HQ53BAQ5I4GAERÈ+ÒÈGA43IOHAUNVKANE124RÈ+fioureahjkgaeu+-re*
```

was input the expected output would be:

```
*your string:
R3HQ53BAQ5I4GAERÈ+ÒÈGA43IOHAUNVKANE124RÈ+fioureahjkgaeu+-reR3HQ53BAQ5I4GAERÈ+ÒÈGA43IOHAUNVKANE124RÈ+fioureahjkgaeu+-reR3HQ53BAQ5I4GAERÈ+ÒÈGA43IOHAUNVKANE124RÈ+fioureahjkgaeu+-reR3HQ53BAQ5I4GAERÈ+ÒÈGA43IOHAUNVKANE124RÈ+fioureahjkgaeu+-reR3HQ53BAQ5I4GAERÈ+ÒÈGA43IOHAUNVKANE124RÈ+fioureahjkgaeu+-re
this is your string all in lowercase and containing only letters: rhqbaqigaergaiohaunvkanerfioureahjkgaeurerhqbaqigaergaiohaunvkanerfioureahjkgaeurerhqbaqigaergaiohaunvkanerfioureahjkgaeurerhqbaqigaergaiohaunvkanerfioureahjkgaeurerhq
what do you want to do?
press 1 for case 1
press 2 for case 2
press 3 for case 3*
```

but it actually outputs this:

```
*your string:
R3HQ53BAQ5I4GAERÈ+ÒÈGA43IOHAUNVKANE124RÈ+fioureahjkgaeu+-reR3HQ53BAQ5I4GAERÈ+ÒÈGA43IOHAUNVKANE124RÈ+fioureahjkgaeu+-reR3HQ53BAQ5I4GAERÈ+ÒÈGA43IOHAUNVKANE124RÈ+fioureahjkgaeu+-reR3HQ53BAQ5I4GAERÈ+ÒÈGA43IOHAUNVKANE124RÈ+fioureahjkgaeu+-reR3HQ53BAQ5I4GAERÈ+ÒÈGA43IOHAUNVKANE124RÈ+fioureahjkgaeu+-re
this is your string all in lowercase and containing only letters: rhqbaqigaergaiohaunvkanerfioureahjkgaeurerhqbaqigaergaiohaunvkanerfioureahjkgaeurerhqbaqigaergaiohaunvkanerfioureahjkgaeurerhqbaqigaergaiohaunvkanerfioureahjkgaeurerhq
what do you want to do?
press 1 for case 1
press 2 for case 2
press 3 for case 3
**insert a valid input***
```

Why is this? How can I fix this?

Comment: Well, it is behaving exactly as intended. You are telling it to read up to 257 characters. So the rest are left in the stream and is picked up by the next call.

Comment: After your second `for` loop, you want: `stringakek[j] = 0;` to add the nul string terminator.

Comment: You can tell if the length constraint was hit by the absense of the newline (except maybe the last line of a file doesn't have a newline). If so, reallocate the buffer and read more of the same line.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up for me, but how can I prevent it from doing that? I need the string to be cut off after 256 carachters but I don't want it to get it picked up by the next call.

Comment: By having a buffer large enough to read a whole line, and truncating it yourself to the max length you want. Then you can throw away the rest of the buffer, but it has to be read.

Comment: (1) Read the entire line (2) Discard the portion you don't want.  Or you can read it in smaller pieces if you don't want to have to store the entire thing.  The point is you need to consume the entire line before trying to read the next one.

Comment: Or `fgetc` in a loop till `\n`, discarding the characters.

Comment: Do you have the `getline()` function available in your system's C library?

Comment: Probably not, the compiler gives an "implicit declaration" error. Anyway I am sorry I can't upvote comments yet, but thanks everyone for helping!